# How to send data to Excel function to modify sheet via interface?

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I have a team that has to collect data outputs from various inputs (all the data will have the same format). They collect this info in a notebook, and then input it and format it in Excel. I want them to be able to input this info from tablets on an interface, maybe a web page via a POST form, maybe a Excel form, maybe use SharePoint; and send it to the Excel sheet, and format it to match the current format.
Is there a way to do this? There will be multiple people using the interface at the same time, I don't know if this is going to be a problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: forms.office.com perhaps?

Comment: I need Office 365 Bussiness for this @jkpieterse

Comment: Since you mentioned sharepoint I assumed that you already had a Microsoft 365 for business account.